# What is the advantage of `rlist`?

Tags: python

Why is [rlist](http://composingprograms.com/versions/v1/pages/23-sequences.html#recursive-lists) data structure needed? What are some of its advantages?

If the example was shown as `(4, (3, (2, (1, None))))`, I would have thought that it can be extended to `(5, (4 (3, (2, (1, None)))))` and that would have made complete sense just like any other linked lists.

But since the example is `(1, (2, (3, (4, None))))`, extending it outward like `(5, (1, (2, (3, (4, None)))))`, although possible, *seems* to be in the opposite direction of the data shown. I get a feeling that that is not the intention of such a data structure. Extending `(4, None)` is not possible since `tuples` can't be modified.

So, what is the real purpose of such a data structure? Even if it is possible to extend it, I don't see why is it better than `(1, 2, 3, 4)`!

Since the course is adapted from Scheme, are they trying to show Scheme's [lists](https://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/ftpdir/scheme-7.4/doc-html/scheme_8.html)? If so, does Scheme's `lists` grow or is it static? Even the Lisp's [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons) shows `cons` getting constructed like `(cons 5 x)` to show `(5 1 2 3)` which is is really counter-intuitive for a beginner like me.

I am trying to fit the bits and pieces, please do help!

Comment: While there are actually practical use cases for this thing, it's mostly just an example, and probably a holdover from a more recursion-focused Scheme course.

Comment: That's effectively how `lisp` like langages construct a list (from elementary pairs), but it isn't how Python does it.  And Python programmers rarely if ever need to construct it for themselves.

Comment: @user2357112 I couldn't see any practical uses case tbh. Probably need to look deeper though. @hpaulj, so you mean its supposed to grow and not be a static one? If so the example's number choice seems odd. `(4(3(2(1,None))))` would have made sense. Because its apparent that I can make it `(5,(4,(3,(2,1)))))`, In other words does Scheme `list` have growth in mind? If so the number choices here seems odd.

Comment: @Nishant: One big thing is that multiple rlists can share tails. I've used the concept to efficiently record paths from the root in a breadth-first search. Using regular lists would have required lots of copies, expensive in both time and space.

Comment: @user2357112: Incidentally, pathfinding is *exactly* the same thing I've also used an rlist for, though using other algorithms than BFS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was already mentioned in the comments, but to post it as an answer:

Recursive lists (which aren't Scheme-specific) are useful in two contexts:

1. When you need an immutable data structure (e.g. for parallelism, or in functional programming)
2. When you need an efficient representation of lots of lists that share the same tail (e.g. a tree)

This is because they allow extending a list *without* modifying the original list.

This can come up when finding paths in a graph. Say, for example, that you're trying to find the N best paths from your house to your workplace (think Google Maps), you start searching from the workplace (your destination) and considering different streets, moving backwards until you find your house.<sup>1</sup>

What happens here is that many of the paths will share the same "suffixes", and hence you will only want to share those portions and represent them once, to save both memory (since you don't duplicate paths) and time (since you don't have to spend time copying a previous path just to add a different prefix).

Now here you might think "why would I want more than a handful of paths to my destination?" Well, *you* might not want to if "you" just refers to you as one person at a given point in time. But if you're trying to do something like simulating many drivers under different traffic conditions (e.g. at different points in time), then suddenly saving memory and computation time will matter a ton, and the ability to share parts of data structures and build on top of them in parallel can make a massive difference.

<sub><sup>1</sup> You can also search forward with some algorithms, but backwards is a bit more generic. In any case, the direction isn't important here.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the insights @Mehrdad. I will ponder over this!